# Getting code objects tree in Python

Tags: python, object, tree

I am looking to print a tree of my object hierarchy in Python. Basically, after having declared all my objects, I would like to print the object hierarchy.

For example, if an object A has an object B in attribute, I would like to print a tree where A is the root and B the leaf.

Is it possible to do so in Python? I have looked at ast module but it is not what I would like to do.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `dir(your_object)` should get you started.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late answer. Dir looks OK but after a bit of try, it is not what I am looking for. I think I am just going to develop it myself.